# Where is the location of php5.6-fpm.sock?

Tags: php, nginx, php-5.6

I'm connected in my vagrant ubuntu 14.04 x64 machine and I can't find the location of php5.6-fpm.sock under the classic location `/var/run/php...`

Comment: What are the contents of your php fpm configuration file?

Comment: Find the process ID of your `php-fpm` using `ps aux | grep php-fpm`. Using that process ID, find which file descriptors it has open and search for .sock: `sudo lsof -p 1337 | grep sock` where `1337` is the process ID of `php-fpm` master process. However, why do you need the location of that file anyway?

Comment: why do I need php5-fpm.sock ? We need to specify the url to this file when configuring a Nginx server right ? And normally it is under `/var/run/php...`. So I get that : `14:php-fpm5. 31937 root  mem    REG              252,0    92264  397281 /usr/lib/php/20131226/sockets.so
69:php-fpm5. 31937 root    5u  unix 0xffff88003c11ea00      0t0   42764 socket
70:php-fpm5. 31937 root    6u  unix 0xffff88003c11ed80      0t0   42765 socket
`

Comment: @v7d8dpo4 I can't post it, stackoverflow says is too mush code... but there's a lot of thing commented, and zero occurence of ".sock" or "socket"

Comment: The look for the config file that fpm loaded, open it and check whether your fpm uses unix socket (sock file) or TCP one.

Comment: Don't forget that you can omit all lines beginning with `#` and empty lines when you post a configuration file. Also don't forget that you can use pastebin.

Answer (score 7):

The location of the socket is specified in the configuration:

```
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm/php5-fpm.socket
```

in:

```
/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

You could also try

- `ps aux | grep php` like mentioned in the comments.
- look in a `phpinfo();`
- use `find` or `locate`
- browse the directories which are typical for unix sockets like `/run`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, the file has moved to this location:

```
/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock
```